# Minimizing/Maximizing java swing gui executes actionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing

So I'm a complete beginner in Java swing gui. I am going through Head First Java as  the starting book. I made a simple gui in which a button is there and pressing it creates different gradient on a circle above it. The code is all in the book. It works fine when i click the button. However, when i maximize/minimize the gui, it acts as if the button is pressed and gradient changes. Why does this happen?

GUI code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SimpleGuiC implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGuiC gui=new SimpleGuiC();
    gui.go();
}
    public  void go(){
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Gradient changer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton button=new JButton("Change colors");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    MyDrawPanel drawPanel=new MyDrawPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

Random gradient generating code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import  javax.swing.*;
public class MyDrawPanel extends  JPanel{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70,70,startColor, 150,150, endColor);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70,70,100,100);
    }

}
```

[image: Minimized version]
[image: After maximizing]

Comment: Because paintComponent is the method called by Swing evey time it needs to ... paint the component. And since resizing the frame resizes the component, the component needs to be repainted. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-

Comment: How does one prevent the repaint then

Comment: This example from your book, unless it precisely wants to demonstate that, is a bad example. A button which says "change colors" should change the colors, and store them in fields, and then repaint. The paintComponent() shouldn't do something random every time it's called: it should use the colors set in the fields when clicking the button, and use them to paint the circle.

Comment: How can i change gradient then? without calling repaint everytime

Comment: I already explained that in my previous comment. Choose the random colors when the button is pressed, store them in fields, and repaint. In the paintComponent, don't do anything random. Use the colors stored in the fields, which will only change when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although i have no idea how to implement what you just said

Comment: See my answer for a complete implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the implementation suggested in my comments:

```
public final class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private Color startColor;
    private Color endColor;

    public MyDrawPanel() {
        this.changeColors();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
    }

    public void changeColors() {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        this.startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        this.endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the panel has a state (i.e. fields), containing the colors that the circle must have. These colors don't change in `paintComponent()`. They only change when the `changeColors()` method is called.

```
public class SimpleGuiC implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private MyDrawPanel drawPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            SimpleGuiC gui = new SimpleGuiC();
            gui.go();
        });
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Gradient changer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Change colors");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.drawPanel.changeColors();
    }
}
```

And, as you can see here, the `actionPerformed()` method changes the state of the panel (i.e. the colors it must display). It does what the button says it does: change the colors. Each time the panel is repainted, it will always use the colors that were set the last time `changeColors()` has been called.

Answer (score 1):

People in the comments told you why it happens. All you now have to do is create a boolean that will tell if it was pressed or not and then check.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SimpleGuiC implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;

    MyDrawPanel drawPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGuiC gui=new SimpleGuiC();
    gui.go();
}
    public  void go(){
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Gradient changer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton button=new JButton("Change colors");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        drawPanel.buttonPressed = true;

        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

DrawPanel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import  javax.swing.*;
public class MyDrawPanel extends  JPanel{

public boolean buttonPressed = false;

private GradientPaint gradient;

public MyDrawPanel () {
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (buttonPressed) {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);


        buttonPressed = false;
    }
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
}

}
```

Basically what this does is every time the button is pressed, the boolean will be set to true. Then when repainting, it will check if it's true and if yes, it will paint it and set it back to false so it can go again. Good Luck!

**EDIT:**

To make it not disappear. You need to separate the code for changing the gradient and for painting. So, paint every single time, but only change the gradient when the button is pressed. I hope this code I just updated will work.

**EDIT 2:**

Don't forget to encapsulate that variable, I didn't because I was in hurry, but just make it private and add getters and setters!

Comment: Now the circle disappears when i maximize or minimize the gui. Since buttonPressed is false, when paintComponent gets called, it doesnt execute the circle code, and all i see is a blank screen

Comment: @VaibhavPandey i fixed and tested the code, it no longer disappears :)

Comment: (1-) No, don't use a boolean variable. Painting logic should paint the state of the component, not change the state. You should NOT be generating random colors in the painting method.

Comment: @camickr I know it's not the place to do it, but, it's just the way that he did it so I just made his code work. The fact that the code isn't written to well is not my fault.

Comment: Adding the variable makes the bad code worse. The point of the forum is to fix problems not add onto the problem.

Comment: @camickr well at least his code now works as expected. If you think you have a better solution than mine, then go and write it..........

Comment: Yes please, i want to see how to repaint it without using paintComponent
Edit:Without randomly generating colors in paintComponent

Comment: @VaibhavPandey you can't repaint without using paintComponent. camickr complained about something  else not that. What do you think is wrong with my answer that you won't tick it?

Comment: `What do you think is wrong with my answer` - it doesn't show anything about proper design for the future and will lead to additional problems when other features need to be added.

Comment: @camickr Then, go and write your own answer that is better than mine. What are you complaining if you don't know the solution by yourself.....

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer if you want to know the proper solution.